# Can't boot windows 10 after installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Okay.

So I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a 2nd SATA hard drive. Windows looks like from `fdisk -l` that it's on `/dev/sdc`.  After installing Ubuntu, I'm unable to boot into Windows.

I've tried `sudo update-grub`, using the boot-repair utility (https://paste.ubuntu.com/26276069/), and trying to adding Windows manually to the grub2's 40_custom file, (may have done wrong, but I removed it as it said it couldn't find it).  I've disabled Fast Boot in the BIOS etc.  I've tried selecting the drive that Windows is installed on in the BIOS boot menu, and it still boots right into ubuntu.  I'm not sure what to do and would love if someone could help point me in the right direction.

update-grub output: https://pastebin.com/Uz0U7qGf

EDIT: Tried disconnecting the SATA drive Ubuntu is installed on, and it wouldn't boot anything and just asked for me to insert boot media.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is one method that I know, could restore Windows 7 MBR, you may try it for Windows 10 too, as below:

1. Boot with Ubuntu Live environment with DVD/USB
2. Open Terminal and issue `sudo apt-get install mbr` command
3. After MBR installs, issue `sudo install-mbr -i n -p D -t 0 /dev/sdx` (here x=drive name)
4. Reboot

Hope this helps, thanks :)

Comment: According to the Boot Repair  Boot Info Script MBR is already installed on sdb and sdc. GRUB is installed in the MBR of sdb, Windows is installed on sdc,   and `No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc`.